# Sticky div after fixed div

Tags: jquery, css

I have top menu which is fixed to top on scroll...

```
.top-menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I am trying to use position fixed to an div...

```
.t-div {
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Everything seems to be working and css is fine, its not the case...
This is wordpress site I am using and problem comes with sticked div when wordpress ads topbar if I am logged in, than this "top: 50px;" is not accurate anymore.

I tried position fixed for second div, or t-div but than even more problems appear than with using sticky position.

I won't mind even jquery solution, if it can't by css.

Comment: Wordpress topbar is 32px. You can set your top property to 82px.

Comment: You do not need to do anything because the user will see your site front, not a backend.

Comment: First solution you can set top position on scroll as WordPress top bar comes on scroll or use your second div inside header